# How to ensure order preservation?

Tags: ibm-mq

We have an application that will be publishing messages to a single Topic. The messages are expected to be consumed by multiple Subscriber applications in the exact same order in which they were published.

The complication is that each subscriber will be using a different Message Selector to filter on the messages based on their properties. The filters will be such that there is no overlap among the messages read by the subscribers.
 For e.g.

Time Message Property

t1   m1      red

t2   m2      blue

t3   m3      red

Assuming subscriber S1 subscribes for reading color=red and S2 subscribes for reading color=blue, we need S1 to read m1 and get blocked until S2 reads m2. Only once S2 has read m2, S1 will read m3.

Is this possible with Websphere MQ 7.0, and if so, what configuration should we use for the queue manager and what option should we use in the MQGET operation?

Thanks,
 Yash

Answer (score 1):

In Publish/Subscribe messaging neither the publisher is aware of subscriber nor a subscriber is aware of presence of another subscriber. I don't think any messaging provider will have a feature that you are looking for.

It may be simple for you to implement an event mechanism where S1 informs S2 of receiving message.